# useSubscription skip some of new data

Tags: reactjs, graphql, backend, apollo, apollo-client

I have a state and useSubscription like code below :

```
  const [liveOrderData, setLiveOrderData] = useState(null)

  useSubscription(traderSubscriptions.FIND_LIVE_ORDER_UPDATES, {
    variables: { ...myVariables },

    onData: (res) => {
      setLiveOrderData(res.data.data.findLiveOrderUpdates)
    }
  })
```

but when i try logging result in `useEffect` I don't get all the results that has been logged in Apollo Studio !

```
  useEffect(() => {
    console.log(liveOrderData)
  }, [liveOrderData])
```

usually after each mutation call 5 new data gets logged in Apollo Studio but I only get 3 of them in Client.